# CreateSlice Error Uncaught ReferenceError: returnfalse is not defined

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I have used Redux Toolkit several times before and have never been this error when creating a slice.

```
const initialState = {
  value : 0
}

export const counteSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'counter',
    initialState, 
    reducers: {
       increment: (state, action) => {
                 state.value += 1
             }
    }

})
```

The error occured at initialState.

```
initialState: 0
```

or

```
function setInitialState() {
return {
value: 0
   }
}

....slice
initialState: () => setInitialstate
....
```

are fine.But these are not correct ways to use toolkit I think.

The error says,
[returnfalse is not defined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifHOp.png)

Comment: i think you'd want a space there `return false` instead of `returnfalse`. Its a reference error, meaning `returnfalse` is being treated as an undefined variable

Comment: @kritiz  yes, I thought the error is weired becasue I didn't return any 'false' in my code. Then is it a library's problem ?

Comment: Could be a typo? `export const counteSlice = ...` should be `counterSlice`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by the webpack version. I used webpack v.4.22, but it was solved once I downgraded to v.4.21. (Upgrade is better)

I found this when I'm trying to use styled component and there was same error. I found solution at https://github.com/styleguidist/react-styleguidist/issues/1181